# Append substring from filename to each row of CSV

Tags: bash, shell, csv

I have a folder containing some .CSV files:

```
/folder/
  file1.csv
  file2.csv
  file3.csv
  ...
```

And each file contains some 500 rows of CSV. I want to concatenate these files but append the number in the filename to the end of each row in each file.

So if `file1.csv` was:

```
0.00, 1.00, 0.54, 0.29
0.10, 1.00, 0.32, 0.92
0.31, 0.94, 0.22, 0.22
```

And `file2.csv` was:

```
0.50, 1.00, 0.84, 0.23
0.16, 0.40, 0.92, 0.94
0.34, 0.54, 0.62, 0.62
```

I want my final output to be, say, `combined.csv` which looks like this:

```
0.00, 1.00, 0.54, 0.29, 1
0.10, 1.00, 0.32, 0.92, 1
0.31, 0.94, 0.22, 0.22, 1
0.50, 1.00, 0.84, 0.23, 2
0.16, 0.40, 0.92, 0.94, 2
0.34, 0.54, 0.62, 0.62, 2
```

Note all rows in `file1.csv` had a `, 1` appended to each row and in `file2.csv`, `, 2` was appended to each row. If the filename were `fileN.csv` I want `, N` to be appended to each row. It can be assumed each file only has 1 digit (`0-9`).

I already know how to concatenate .CSV files: `cat *.csv > combined.csv`, but how do I grab the file number and append that number to each row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you try the following:

```
cd folder
for f in file*.csv; do
    num=${f//[^0-9]/}        # extract number from the filename
    sed "s/$/, $num/" "$f"   # append the number to each line
done > combined.csv
```

combined.csv:

```
0.00, 1.00, 0.54, 0.29, 1
0.10, 1.00, 0.32, 0.92, 1
0.31, 0.94, 0.22, 0.22, 1
0.50, 1.00, 0.84, 0.23, 2
0.16, 0.40, 0.92, 0.94, 2
0.34, 0.54, 0.62, 0.62, 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `sed 's/$/ file_number/' filename` to each file, then cat filename.csv >> combined.csv

Answer (score 0):

Here's an awk / sed combo for you:

```
awk '
  { print $0 "," FILENAME } 
' *.csv | sed 's/,[A-Za-z]*\([0-9]\).csv$/, \1/'
```

There is an assumption that all filenames look similar to fileX.csv, but you can play with the `sed` portion to match your input.